# Is it possible to transfer an enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking around a bit, but everything that I found was from around a year ago or so, I was hoping someone on here could help answer my question.

Is it possible to transfer an enchantment that is already on a tool, say like on an iron pickaxe or a gold pickaxe onto a book or something? But only in survival, no commands, cheats or anything like that?

Currently in 1.14.2 Java edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot transfer an enchantment from a tool onto a book in vanilla survival without cheats.

You can however combine two books (or any two items of the same type) and merge the enchantments with an anvil.

[See here for more information on enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting)

Answer (score -2):

However there's a program called Universal Minecraft Editor
It edits everything in a Minecraft world, like the inventory, and the enchantments in tools.
You can use the program to remove the enchantment without cheats enabled, but does it count as cheating?